# GAM - make 2D spline depend on 2 dummy variables

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

Let us say I have 2 continuous variables x1 and x2 and 2 factors f1 and month. Factor f1 has 2 levels and factor month 12. I know how to express the model for x1 and x2 for the target y:

```
gam(y ~ s(x1, x2))
```

Just wondering, how can I have a spline for each factor/level combination for f1 + month (bit like in a hierarchical model). Thanks!

Comment: Check `bs="re"` and `bs="mrf"` for what you want.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks. I will read up on this. Could you possibly propose an example gam expression as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @usεr11852 I'm really not seeing how either of those would help here? How were you thinking of creating the neighbour matrix to generate the penalty for the MRF?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: I mostly focused on `re` but I didn't know what the factor meant so also mentioned `mrf`. But hey, your answer also checks `re`. +1 there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two main options:

1. random splines for the combinations given by the interaction of the factors, or
2. `by` factor smooths, with the interaction of the factors used as the `by` variable

I would create `f1f2` in your data frame from the result of `interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE)`, then you could do:

Option 1

```r
y ~ t2(x, y, f1f2, bs = c('tp', 're'), d = c(2,1), full = TRUE)
```

or

```r
y ~ f1f2 + s(x, y, by = f1f2)
```

Which should result in a spline for each level of `f1f2`. The main difference between the two models is that the first uses the same wiggliness for each spline, the second has a separate smoothness parameter (hence wiggliness) for each spline.

Comment: thanks Gavin. I will digest. Btw, is there a good book/tutorial/exhaustive blog about gams? I did a datacamp course a while back but it is too simple ... thanks.

Comment: @cs0815 I would get Simon Wood's book on GAMs: https://books.google.ca/books/about/Generalized_Additive_Models.html?id=JTkkDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y just make sure it is the 2nd edition